# why referenced objects are collected in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I am trying this c# code for better understanding the garbage collection in .Net environment. This code allocate endlessly arrays into a list and a background thread handles the garbage collection notifications. The garbage collection works of course, it can be tested by checking load.Count from time to time and see that the number is decreasing. My question is actually why these objects are garbage collected? since they are held in a list, they are still referenced, and for my understanding they should not be collected.

The code example is taken from MSDN.

```
 class Program
    {
        // Variable for continual checking in the

        // While loop in the WaitForFullGCProc method. 
        static bool checkForNotify = false;
```

// Variable for suspending work  
    // (such servicing allocated server requests) 
    // after a notification is received and then  
    // resuming allocation after inducing a garbage collection. 
    static bool bAllocate = false;

    // Variable for ending the example. 
    static bool finalExit = false;

    // Collection for objects that   
    // simulate the server request workload. 
    static List<byte[]> load = new List<byte[]>();


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Register for a notification. 
            GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(10, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Registered for GC notification.");

            checkForNotify = true;
            bAllocate = true;

            // Start a thread using WaitForFullGCProc.
            Thread thWaitForFullGC = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WaitForFullGCProc));
            thWaitForFullGC.Start();

            // While the thread is checking for notifications in 
            // WaitForFullGCProc, create objects to simulate a server workload. 
            try
            {

                int lastCollCount = 0;
                int newCollCount = 0;


                while (true)
                {
                    if (bAllocate)
                    {
                        load.Add(new byte[1000]);
                        newCollCount = GC.CollectionCount(2);
                        if (newCollCount != lastCollCount)
                        {
                            // Show collection count when it increases:
                            Console.WriteLine("Gen 2 collection count: {0}", GC.CollectionCount(2).ToString());
                            lastCollCount = newCollCount;
                        }

                        // For ending the example (arbitrary). 
                        if (newCollCount == 500)
                        {
                            finalExit = true;
                            checkForNotify = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Out of memory.");
            }


            finalExit = true;
            checkForNotify = false;
            GC.CancelFullGCNotification();

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException invalidOp)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("GC Notifications are not supported while concurrent GC is enabled.\n"
                + invalidOp.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void OnFullGCApproachNotify()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Redirecting requests.");

        // Method that tells the request queuing   
        // server to not direct requests to this server. 
        RedirectRequests();

        // Method that provides time to  
        // finish processing pending requests. 
        FinishExistingRequests();

        // This is a good time to induce a GC collection 
        // because the runtime will induce a full GC soon. 
        // To be very careful, you can check precede with a 
        // check of the GC.GCCollectionCount to make sure 
        // a full GC did not already occur since last notified.
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("Induced a collection.");

    }


    public static void OnFullGCCompleteEndNotify()
    {
        // Method that informs the request queuing server 
        // that this server is ready to accept requests again.
        AcceptRequests();
        Console.WriteLine("Accepting requests again.");
    }

    public static void WaitForFullGCProc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // CheckForNotify is set to true and false in Main. 
            while (checkForNotify)
            {
                // Check for a notification of an approaching collection.
                GCNotificationStatus s = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach();
                if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GC Notification raised.");
                    OnFullGCApproachNotify();
                }
                else if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Canceled)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GC Notification cancelled.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // This can occur if a timeout period 
                    // is specified for WaitForFullGCApproach(Timeout)  
                    // or WaitForFullGCComplete(Timeout)   
                    // and the time out period has elapsed. 
                    Console.WriteLine("GC Notification not applicable.");
                    break;
                }

                // Check for a notification of a completed collection.
                s = GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
                if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GC Notifiction raised.");
                    OnFullGCCompleteEndNotify();
                }
                else if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Canceled)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GC Notification cancelled.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Could be a time out.
                    Console.WriteLine("GC Notification not applicable.");
                    break;
                }
            }


            Thread.Sleep(500);
            // FinalExit is set to true right before   
            // the main thread cancelled notification. 
            if (finalExit)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    private static void RedirectRequests()
    {
        // Code that sends requests 
        // to other servers. 

        // Suspend work.
        bAllocate = false;

    }

    private static void FinishExistingRequests()
    {
        // Code that waits a period of time 
        // for pending requests to finish. 

        // Clear the simulated workload.
        load.Clear();

    }

    private static void AcceptRequests()
    {
        // Code that resumes processing 
        // requests on this server. 

        // Resume work.
        bAllocate = true;

    }
}

Comment: You might consider actually reading the documentation for [`GC.CollectionCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collectioncount(v=vs.110).aspx). It returns the number of times the garbage collector ran, not the number of objects collected.

Comment: Where are you checking `lst.Count`? It should *never* decrease the way you have it.

Comment: The arrays that you are allocating are never unreferenced; hence, never garbage collected. You're just accumulating them in `lst` but never letting them go.

Comment: You should include the code for checking `lst.Count` in your sample, and provide the output. I sincerely doubt that the value is decreasing with the code you've posted.

Comment: load.Count can be checked right after printing Console.WriteLine("Gen 2 collection count: {0}", GC.CollectionCount(2).ToString());

Answer (score 3):

Here is my modified version of your program:

```
class Program
{
    List<byte[]> myJunkList = new List<byte[]>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.Run();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(10, 10);

        var pollingThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var gcStatus = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach(1000);

                switch (gcStatus)
                {
                    case GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded:
                        Console.WriteLine("GC has started.");
                        break;
                }

                gcStatus = GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(1000);

                switch (gcStatus)
                {
                    case GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded:
                        Console.WriteLine("GC has ended.");
                        break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });
        pollingThread.Start();

        AllocateMemory();

        GC.CancelFullGCNotification();
    }

    void AllocateMemory()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        var newCount = 0;
        var oldCount = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            var junk = new byte[1024];
            rand.NextBytes(junk);

            myJunkList.Add(junk);

            newCount = GC.CollectionCount(2);

            if (newCount != oldCount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GC 2 has run {0} times (list now has {1} items).", newCount, myJunkList.Count);
            }
            oldCount = newCount;
        }
    }
```

The output shows this:

```
GC has started.
GC 2 has run 1 times (list now has 14935 items).
GC has ended.
GC 2 has run 2 times (list now has 33146 items).
GC 2 has run 3 times (list now has 55403 items).
GC 2 has run 4 times (list now has 95877 items).
GC 2 has run 5 times (list now has 166723 items).
GC has ended.
GC 2 has run 6 times (list now has 292218 items).
GC has ended.
GC has ended.
GC 2 has run 7 times (list now has 539165 items).
GC has ended.
GC has ended.
GC has ended.
GC 2 has run 8 times (list now has 986512 items).
GC has ended.
GC has ended.
GC has started.
GC has ended.
GC has started.
```

As you can see, the list is **not** being collected and eventually you get an `OutOfMemoryException` as expected.

Comment: notice my edit, I brought the wrong code, I replaced it with the new one